# How to create quasi-copy of a file

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to create quasi-copy of my directory with sensitive data.

Then I would like to share this quasi-copy with others to provide so called 'real data'.

This 'real data' would allow others to do tests in matters related to storage performance.

My question is how to create copy of any file ( text, jpeg, sqlite.db, ... ) that will not contain any of its original data, but from point of view of compression, de-duplication and so on would be very similar.

I appreciate any pointers to tools, libs that helps with creating such quasi copy.

I appreciate any pointers what to measure and how to measure similarity of original file and its quasi copy.

Comment: So the copy should not contain the original data, but "similar" data??? You would have to define, what "similar" means, in particular if you have binary data involved (as your sqlite.db example suggests). Under which condition do you consider two bit-patterns similar?

Comment: Good question. I do not know. I think about comparing compression level (bzip2) of both files as measure. But don't know to much about filesystems, storage solution ( compression, de-duplication, lto compression, ... ) so I not sure if this approach is valid.

Comment: You can find a "valid approach" only after you define your metric for similarity. Using the compression level of a file for this sounds to me like a weird approach, though theoretically, it perhaps is feasible (though likely costly). You would have to generate some random files and calculate their compression level, and if you find one "similar" to the one you are going to replace, you take this one. But I wonder what's the point of the whole exercise - what do you gain from it?

Comment: If I had such quasi-data I could share it without sharing sensitive data ( as I described ).

Comment: There are a lot of ways storage appliance maybe configured, and with those 'real data' they could test and give me more realistic, more precise performance description evaluation ( as I described ).

Comment: One again I can write I do not know what is proper measure and how to achieve it.
I couldn't find solution to this problem, that is why I post my question.

Comment: It seems that your proper "measure" of "similarity" is simply whether the copy behaves the same in the storage performance analysis as the real data would.  But, you can't know that without using real data for that analysis!  (What clearly you cannot do for it would reveal that data.) The one way I can think of is to build a replacement file using a candidate approach and then use it (yourself) for individual components that the analysis includes. Does it compress (roughly) the same?  How about de-duplication? How about ...?  Etc. Then make your choices.

Comment: [cont'd] If the approach you use is flexible enough then you can adjust your masking for whichever part of analysis "failed" (copy behaved substantially differently).  If compression was very different perhaps refine your algorithm to study words and produce more similar obfuscation, etc.

Comment: @nnnTom : Your description is pretty fuzzy. I recommend to start small, say with a simple text file having 10 lines of random text, each line consisting of several words. Now think what **requirements** a **similar** file must have: The same number of lines, the same number of words per line, whether the words must contain of the identical characters of the corresponding original word (but maybe permuted), and so on. Once you have specified this, you can proceed to more general (binary) files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether a "quasi-copy" is an established notion and whether there are accepted rules and procedures. But here is a crude take on how to "[mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking)" data for protection: replace words by equal-length sequences of (perhaps adjusted) random characters.  One cannot then do a very accurate storage analysis of real data but that has to suffer after any data scrambling.

One way to build such a "quasi-word," wrapped in a program for convenience

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $word = shift // die "Usage: $0 word\n";

my @alphabet = 'a'..'z';

my $quasi_word;

foreach my $c (split '', $word) { 
    if (looks_like_number($c)) {
        $quasi_word .= int rand 10;
    }
    else {
        $quasi_word .= $alphabet[int rand 26];
    }
}

say $quasi_word;
```

This doesn't cut it at all for a de-duplication analysis. For that one can replace repeated words by the same random sequence, for example as follows.

First make a pass over the words from the file and build a frequency hash, of how many times each word appears.  Then as each word is processed it is first checked whether it repeats, and if it does a random replacement is built only the first time and later that is used every time.

Further adjustments for specific needs should be easy to add.

Any full masking (scrambling/tokenization...) of data of course cannot allow a precise analysis of compression of real data using such a mangled set.

If you know specific sensitive parts then only those can be masked  and that would improve the accuracy of the following analyses considerably.

This will be slow but if a set of files need be built once in a while it shouldn't matter.

---

*A question was raised of the "criteria" for the "similarity" of masked data, and the question itself was closed for lack of detail.  Here is a comment on that.*

It seems that only "measure" of "similarity" is simply whether the copy behaves the same in the storage performance analysis as the real data would.  But, one can't tell without using real data for that analysis! (What clearly would reveal that data.)

The one way I can think of is to build a copy using a candidate approach and then use it (yourself) for individual components of that  analysis. Does it compress (roughly) the same?  How about de-duplication? How about ...?  Etc. Then make your choices.

If the used approach is flexible enough the masking can then be adjusted for whichever part of analysis "failed" -- the copy behaved substantially differently.  (If compression was very different perhaps refine your algorithm to study words and produce more similar obfuscation, etc.)